# flutter doctor error in macOs high sierra

Tags: macos, flutter

[image]**flutter doctor command show operation not permitted in macOS**

I don't know why when. I run flutter doctor it's showing
**zsh: operation not permitted: flutter**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to grant full disk access to terminal app.  View the thread here on how to do that.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65101

In the future, I would recommend a simple google search of your exact error before posting a new question.  I found the solution above by searching "zsh: operation not permitted: flutter macOS"

Comment: Thanx for your fast response…
Yes, I did that already I have tried all the methods available on the related issues.

In your answer grant full disk access it is available in macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (or higher version of macOS) but that functionally not available in macOS high sierra 10.13.6

Comment: @akshayyadav - Maybe this will help.  It's a support page for a random piece of software but I think it might apply here.  https://www.protectmac.com/support/highsierra.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have already allowed the terminal Full Disk Access under Security and P

Instead of downloading Flutter use git clone

https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Add your path example:  export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/flutter/bin"
(if the flutter folder is on the user home)

then you can do flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

This is also the problem on my side. I disabled slp and gave full permissions but still reported errors：zsh: operation not permitted: flutter

Is there another solution?

Need help, thank you!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34247493)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that macOS has applied a quarantine extended attribute to the Flutter Doctor executable. Find the full path to the executable in your Flutter installation and perform the steps below:

Check the extended attributes of the script by running:

`xattr -l PATH/TO/FLUTTER-DOCTOR`

If `com.apple.quarantine` is present in the list of attributes displayed then you need to remove that attribute.

You can do this using:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine PATH/TO/FLUTTER-DOCTOR`

Note that this same issue can occur with any bash script or executable including new scripts that you may write as part of your general workflow, CI scripts etc. I just ran into this on Ventura for a simple script to clean my development environment.

If macOS does decide to apply the quarantine attribute to a custom script then one last required step is to ensure that the script is still executable, which you can do using:

`chmod +x PATH/TO/AFFECTED-SCRIPT.SH`